NextJS with ASP.NET Core Web API
So I have a problem the backend is containerized which could be a cause, but Im not sure thats why Im posting a question. The problem is that when I try to make a request to the backend I get this error DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT
Ive tried using the --experimental-https to the run dev command and it didnt work.
The problem is that even when I explicitly only expose the insecure port through the docker-compose.yml file (8080) it doesnt work and there is still a secure connection available and when I even try to make the request to the insecure connection I still get the same error.
These are the Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml and the fitnessPlannerAPICalls.ts:
Dockerfile
# See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

# This stage is used when running from VS in fast mode (Default for Debug configuration)
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
# Uncomment the line below to enable HTTPS
#EXPOSE 8081


# This stage is used to build the service project
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["FitnessPlannerAPI/FitnessPlannerAPI.csproj", "FitnessPlannerAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./FitnessPlannerAPI/FitnessPlannerAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/FitnessPlannerAPI"
RUN dotnet build "./FitnessPlannerAPI.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

# This stage is used to publish the service project to be copied to the final stage
FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./FitnessPlannerAPI.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

# This stage is used in production or when running from VS in regular mode (Default when not using the Debug configuration)
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "FitnessPlannerAPI.dll"]

docker-compose.yml
networks:
  fitnessplanner:
    driver: bridge

services:
  fitnessplannerapi:
    container_name: fitnessplannerapi
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}fitnessplannerapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: FitnessPlannerAPI/Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - "1337:8080"
      # Uncomment the line below to enable HTTPS
      #- "1337:8081"
    depends_on:
      - fitnessplannersqlserver
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=fitnessplannersqlserver
      - DB_NAME=FitnessPlannerDB
      - DB_SA_PASSWORD=your-secure-pw
    networks:
      - fitnessplanner
  fitnessplannersqlserver:
    container_name: fitnessplannersqlserver
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=your-secure-pw
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/opt/mssql/data
      - ./log:/var/opt/mssql/log
      - ./secrets:/var/opt/mssql/secrets
    networks:
      - fitnessplanner


fitnessPlannerAPICalls.ts
"use server"

// Define the user schema as a TypeScript interface
export interface UserInitialSetupSchema {
  userId: string;
  age: number;
  gender: string;
  height: number;
  weight: number;
  fitnessLevel: string;
  fitnessGoal: string;
  workoutFrequency: number;
}

export async function addUserInitialSetup(data : UserInitialSetupSchema)
{
  // USING ENCRYPTED CONNECTION
  // const apiEndpoint = 'https://localhost:1337/api/userinitialsetup/add';
  // USING UNENCRYPTED CONNECTION
  const apiEndpoint = 'http://localhost:1337/api/userinitialsetup/add';

  try {
    const response = await fetch(apiEndpoint, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });

    switch (response.status) {
      case 200:
        return 'User initial setup added successfully.';
      case 400:
        return 'User already exists.';
      default:
        return 'Something went wrong.' + await response.json();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to add user initial setup:', error);
    return 'Failed to add user initial setup.';
  }
}


You can setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to 0 in your development.  Or don't use https, use http. This problem is often caused by self-signed certificates, especially when the application is trying to be accessed over HTTPS, but the certificate is not signed by a trusted CA.

Fixed it with the enviorment variable fix, but I can't figure out how to make the API use only http even when I explicitly only expose the http port in the docker-compose file. I could just run it with the http option in Visual Studio, but that messes the whole data up since the data on the container server and on the local server is different.
